# extracting information after keyword python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am reading in a file with lines of data that look like this:

```
ifgfilename: 150304SN.0045; Channel: 1; Name of location: Boulder; Latitude of location: 40.038; Longitude of location: -105.243;
```

I need to extract the information so I wrote a regex code like this:

```
import re

with open('/Users/CALPY output/info.txt', 'rt') as infofile:
    for count, line in enumerate(infofile): 
        with open('\\_spec_final.t15', 'w') as t:
            lat = re.search('^Latitude of location: (.*)', line)
            lon = re.search('^Longitude of location: (.*)', line)
            date = re.search('^Time of measurement (UTC): (.*)', line) 

            print lat
            print lon
            print date
```

however, it is not retrieving the info I want because it just prints out:

```
None
None
None
```

Any idea how to retrieve the numbers I need? (sometimes I will need strings so I need something somewhat flexible)

Comment: Remove the `^` characters - `^` will only match right at the beginning of the line.

Comment: The supplied sample string contains no `Time of measurement (UTC)`. Also, inside a regex pattern the `\(` and `\)` must be escaped. Use `date = re.search('Time of measurement \(UTC\): ([^;]+)', line)`. Check `date` match data object with `if date:` then print the `group(1)` value.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew that worked!

Comment: I don't think I should add  an answer. Actually, Daniel has answered the main part.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are unnecessarily including `^` at the start of each regex which means start of line.  Also change the `.*` to a set of all characters but semicolon (`[^;]+`) to match the value you want. In my tests I had the casing wrong, you might be getting None for the same reason, so I added that as well.

```
lat = re.search('Latitude of location:\s*([^;]+)', line, re.IGNORECASE)
lon = re.search('Longitude of location:\s*([^;]+)', line, re.IGNORECASE)
date = re.search('Time of measurement (UTC):\s*([^;]+)', line, re.IGNORECASE)

print lat.group(1)
print lon.group(1)
print date.group(1)
```

Python also support look behinds, so an alternative that will avoid the unnecessary groupings would be:

```
(?<=Latitude of location: )[^;]+
```

Comment: ... and change the `.*` so as not to swallow the rest of the line :)

Comment: I used your code @Daniel Gimenez but now the output looks like: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10e9c6c60>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10e9c3120>
None

Comment: Thanks, I went for something more explicit than `(.*?);`.

Comment: @alli, like what?  Did you need to print just the lat.group(1) to get the matched value.

Comment: changed it to your new suggestion but receiving same output

Comment: I did try doing the group suggestion but got this: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: I added the ignore case flag. Try printing out the line to make sure its what you expect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117755/discussion-between-alli-and-daniel-gimenez).